# Question about probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've recently came across this question:

```
You are trying to hitch-hike. Cars pass at random intervals, at an average rate of 1 
per minute. The probability of a car giving you a lift is 1%. What is the probability
that you will still be waiting after one hour?
```

My first thought was to use the Binomial distribution. After one hour an average of 60 cars will pass, so the probability of all 60 cars not giving a lift is $\mathcal{P}_{binom}(60;0.999,60)=0.999^{60}=0.547$.

To check this I then retried the calculation using the Poisson distribution, If cars pass at a rate of 1 per minute then $\lambda=0.01\times60=0.6$, so the probability of not getting a lift is $\mathcal{P}_{pois}(0,\lambda=0.6)=e^{-\lambda}=0.549$.

Both answers are very close to each other, but why aren't they exactly equal?

Comment: Assuming pick-ups occur randomly in time, the waiting time to be picked up has a (negative) exponential distribution with mean wait 100 minutes, which should give the same result as your Poisson calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ converges to $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ and $np\rightarrow \lambda$. 
So these probabilities are only asymptotically equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because they model two different things.

A Binomial Distribution, $\mathcal{Bin}(n, p)$, is that the count of successes in of $n$ Bernoulli trials with each trial having independent and identical probability of success $p$.   The count of such successes can range from $0$ to $n$.

A Poisson Distribution, $\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda, \Delta t)$ is that of the count of events occurring within a fixed interval, $\Delta t$, if the subsequent events occur independently of the span since their prior event at a constant rate $\lambda$ per unit interval.   The count of such events can range from $0$ to indefinite; no upper bound.

Only for large $n$ do the two intervals *approach* the same 'shape'.